# How can use an ORACLS EBS xmlreport parameters from a package-body?

Tags: bi-publisher, oraclereports, oracle-ebs, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I have recently created a report using Oracle E-business suite, a XML publisher report. In that report I have added 4 parameters and I need to use those parameters from a package body which is a custom request

these are the parameters in my xml report data definition.

```
<parameters>
        <parameter name="P_org_id" datatype="number"/>
        <parameter name="P_Account_Number" dataType="number"/>
        <parameter name="P_Start_week" dataType="date"/>
        <parameter name="P_End_week" dataType="date"/>

</parameters>
```

Is it possible to access the org_id and p_start_week parameter from the xml report and use it in a package body? I am not sure if I have put the question properly, because I have very limited idea about this. If you need more information to answer this question, please let me know.

this is how the code my package looks like:

```
Select so_header_id from XXONT_M545_CUST_COVG_DATA
where revision_week = &p_current_week – to_char(nvl(<Date_provided_as_parameter>,sysdate),’YYYYMM’)
and cust_org = &p_org_id
and hold_yn = ‘Y’;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create PL/SQL concurrent program
http://www.askhareesh.com/2015/08/plsql-stored-procedure-registration-with-parameters.html

And return data in XML.